# Is slowing your car using the clutch bad for the vehicle?

Tags: driving

I frequently use the clutch to slow myself down while driving, I use it basically everywhere, and was wondering if there are any health effects on the vehicle by doing so?

Obviously doing 50mph and switching into 3rd makes a racket, however, works pretty effectively at slowing the car down without using the brakes (I prefer this in wet conditions).

I don't want to burn my clutch out or cause any other types of damage to my car by doing so, hence is there any information out there on when to performing such maneuvers?

I'd appreciate an explanation on the effect of using the clutch at different speeds, for example:

70mph to 4th gear, 50mph to 3rd gear, 50 mph to 2nd gear, 30 mph to 2nd gear, 30 mph to 1st gear.

Basically, is it bad altogether, is it bad if you're taking it to the extreme, or is it ok in all scenarios.

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Agree with @Solar Mike, but when you do change down the gears you should attempt to match the engine revs to the gearbox revs before releasing the clutch to limit the wear on the clutch friction plates.

Answer (score 2):

Use the brakes, they are cheaper to replace compared to a clutch.

Slipping a clutch is bad practice on any level.